# How to tell if a value exists in a sqlite3 database, python

Tags: python, sqlite

How to tell if a value exists in a sqlite3 database, python

Here is my code so far:

```
def signup():
    email = request.form['email']
    username = request.form['user']
    password = request.form['password']
    g.db.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [email, username, password])
    g.db.commit()
```

I would like it to only insert the values into the database if `email` and `username` aren't in the database, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you have to do is make a query before insertion, and do a [`fetchone`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone). If `fetchone` returns something, then you know for sure that there is a record already in the DB that has the `email` OR `username`:

```
def signup():
    email = request.form['email']
    username = request.form['user']
    password = request.form['password']

    # Create cursor object
    cur = g.db.cursor()

    # run a select query against the table to see if any record exists
    # that has the email or username
    cur.execute("""SELECT email
                          ,username
                   FROM users
                   WHERE email=?
                       OR username=?""",
                (email, username))

    # Fetch one result from the query because it
    # doesn't matter how many records are returned.
    # If it returns just one result, then you know
    # that a record already exists in the table.
    # If no results are pulled from the query, then
    # fetchone will return None.
    result = cur.fetchone()

    if result:
        # Record already exists
        # Do something that tells the user that email/user handle already exists
    else:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (email, username, password))
        g.db.commit()
```

Comment: Couldn't you do it in one line, like: `g.db.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (:email, :username, :password) WHERE users.email <> :email AND users.username <>:username", {"email": email, "username":username, "password": password})` ?

Comment: I am not sure if this what I am asking. If email is in the email column OR user is in the username column I want to to go to the else you put in your code.

Comment: @Daniel Then I would modify to: `SELECT email, username FROM users WHERE email=? or username=?`. You specified "`email` and `username`" so I was assuming you wanted to make both checks. I'll make the changes to my answer.

Comment: ok, i thought it woud be something like that but i wanted to check. thanks

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr it thows up a syntax error for this code:  g.db.execute('SELECT, email username FROM users WHERE email=? or username=?',(email, username))

Comment: @Adonis yes, though I would imagine the app would inform the user if a record exists

Comment: @Daniel "SELECT email, username...", not "SELECT, email username" :P

Comment: I am a little confused please could you comment the code in full

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr  I am a little confused please could you comment the code in full

Comment: @Daniel I have included comments and wrapped my solution in your function. Hope it helps!

Comment: I am really sorry but Now I am getting the error: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchone'

Comment: @Daniel Ah, so your `g.db` object isn't a cursor object. You should create a cursor object before using the `execute` method. I'll edit my answer for that then.

Comment: ok, this really is very good of you.